# JPype - Issue importing & calling methods!

Tags: java, python

Here I'm attaching my code below

```
from jpype import *
from javax.swing import JFrame

classpath = "-Djava.class.path=praat.jar" 
startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(),"-ea",classpath) 

frame = javax.swing.JFrame("Hello JPype")
label = javax.swing.JLabel("Hello JPype!", JLabel.CENTER)
frame.add(label)
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
frame.setSize(200, 100) 
frame.show()
shutdownJVM()
```

When i run this program I get an error.

```
    /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/jpype/_pykeywords.py:18: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  import sets
2010-02-01 22:26:27.473 Python[754:d07] Apple AWT Java VM was loaded on first thread -- can't start AWT.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "swing.py", line 10, in <module>
    frame = javax.swing.JFrame("Hello Jython")
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/jpype/_jpackage.py", line 53, in __call__
    raise TypeError, "Package "+self.__name+" is not Callable"
TypeError: Package javax.swing.JFrame is not Callable
```

Is there any way to solve this problem. A normal Hello World program works fine, but when I'm trying to import packages I get similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Add the Java runtime library (`rt.jar`) to the classpath and try again. The error indicates, that JFrame can't be found but it is inside `rt.jar`.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this and it doesn't work. I tried it on a Linux & a Mac system, it still throws the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

If you import `JFrame` into the local namespace, use it without the full namespace:

```
frame = JFrame("Hello Jython")
```

Same with JLabel, but remember to import it first.

To use the full namespace you need `import javax.swing` instead of `from javax.swing import JFrame`.

Comment: on second thought, maybe that's not your problem at all, sorry